# For iOS 7.1, how can you scale an interface or screen to fit smaller iPhone models?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, layout, interface-builder

apologies in advance if the question has been answered elsewhere, but I have searched and found no equivalent solution.  Feel free to link me if one has been made.

I have built an entire storyboard app (with around 50-60 view controller layouts in a xib file) for the 4-inch iPhone 5/5c/5s, and I am looking for a way to scale down the screen.

By "scale down" I mean automatically take each screen I laid out in storyboard and scaling it by aspect when the program is run on a smaller iPhone, like an iPhone 4S, 4, 3G, or any smaller model compatible with iOS 7.1.

I do not have the time to individually alter the configuration of every single layout item over the storyboard, as that amounts to 1000s of objects, so please restrict any answers or suggestions you have to something on a more massive scale.  Surely, some method of library must exist that allows us to just move everything into a smaller window on a smaller iPhone without clipping or cropping.  Even if the shrinking/scrunching causes blur or font to be less visible, that is much preferable to entire portions of the screen becoming off-screen.

A global setting allowing for a simple aspect scale, multiplying every dimension of every object in the storyboard by destinationPhoneWidth/iPhone5Width for horizontal dimension and destinationPhoneHeight/iPhone5Height would be a satisfactory solution.  I am not aware of one that exists...

Answer (score 0):

One solution is there for your goal to achieve and that is [AUTOLAYOUT](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Beside this ,I don't think there is any library for such goal to achieve and surely this would take a lot of time of your's as per u mention there are 50-60 view controller. Sorry but you should have decided off earlier for compatibility of your app as in size. So all the best with it and keep coding. Also for next time, when starting off with app do keep in compatibility of it as in to avoid such massive work at end.

Comment: How would do this with Autolayout? Be more specific. I've had to uncheck that box for a lot of objects because it messes things up.  Actually, I did decide early on that the app would be compatible, but as you can tell for iPad & other simulators, it seems like common sense that scaling is built-in to IB because you can set 1x and 2x, as if running the app in an iPhone emulator on the larger iPad.  That's what I want to achieve. So I definitely decided very early, and this seems very possible given that for iPad Xcode simulator, you can shrink or expand everything at will with a single click.

Comment: I did click your link, but it's a very general tutorial and not specific to my problem.  Autolayout also refers to individual objects know where to be on the screen, and not mass scale-everything-down-to-fit, which is what I'm looking for.  If you need a better example, go into Xcode, and run/build any iPhone app for the iPad simulator.  See how you can toggle between 1x and 2x?  That effect, only for smaller iPhones.  I want to avoid having to check a box for every single object, plus Autolayout also refers to other things, so please be more specific than posting a link or video.

Comment: Firstly the comment that you wrote is nothing but making you sound rookie. So why did you vote down me. Also autolayout is only way for you to achieve your goal. You will have to apply autolayout on every component of your view controller and run/buil it and check if it fits for both screen or not. Autolayout is a way that make's your screen flexible for both iphone and ipad. Also yes, that's a general link whihc I gave it to you as you don't have idea about autolayout feature so you just can't jump to a expert level unless your a superman(:D)

Comment: so far I haven't seen any lib that would do your goal in a eye blink. So sit down and read about it(autolayout) and it's benefit's. Then you might know. Also don't just vote down if you don't know about feature of apple provide for iphone or ipad.

Comment: Also if you come across any surprising library that does it for you while you just watch your screen then do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1. Use affine transform

Several years ago I scaled iPad layout to iPhone size, without Auto Layout. The solution is to apply [an affine transform](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH2-SW7) to your view hierarchy, just like this:

```
containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(myScale, myScale);
```

Here are some details you'll have to consider.

- You'll probably need to concatenate the scaling transform with some translation transform to locate your view correctly. The order of concatenation does matter.
- Be careful using affine transforms together with Auto Layout. They do work together, but their behavior may change across different iOS versions. Also, you'll probably need to add some translation, both with affine transform and Auto Layout.
- I would wrap all VCs to a root [container VC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html), which solves the task of scaling. However, scaling `UIWindow` directly might also work, I haven't tested this.
- Your view hierarchy will still render to the canvas of the original size, which will be scaled down. So you'll have some blur.

### Solution 2. Resize all frames / constraints recursively in runtime

I'm using this approach in my current project to adjust the layout across different devices. The idea is to get your view, immediately after loading from nib, and to traverse it recursively, multiplying every size. Not only frames, but font sizes, border widths, etc.

Without Auto Layout, you'll have to manipulate frames directly. With Auto Layout, you'll have to take every constraint and multiply its constant.

Here is a category which solves this task with Auto Layout. It takes care of font sizes in `UILabel`, `UITextField`, `UITextView`, `UIButton`, and you'll have to manually extend it with other views you need. Also, you'll have to override `-zoomCustomAttributesWithScale:` and `-shouldMultiplySubviews:` in your custom views.

```
@interface UIView (MultiplyLayout)
- (void)zoomLayoutWithScale:(CGFloat)scale;
- (BOOL)shouldMultiplySubviews;
- (void)zoomCustomAttributesWithScale:(CGFloat)scale;
@end

@implementation UIView (MultiplyLayout)

- (void)zoomLayoutWithScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    CGRect oldFrame = self.frame;
    CGRect newFrame = oldFrame;
    newFrame.size.width *= scale;
    newFrame.size.height *= scale;

    for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.constraints)
        constraint.constant *= scale;

    if (self.shouldMultiplySubviews)
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews)
            [subview zoomLayoutWithScale:scale];

    [self zoomCustomAttributesWithScale:scale];
    self.frame = newFrame;
}

- (void)zoomCustomAttributesWithScale:(CGFloat)scale {
}

- (BOOL)shouldMultiplySubviews {
    return (self.class == [UIView class] ||
            self.class == [UIScrollView class]);
}

@end


@interface UIFont (MultiplyLayout)
- (instancetype)zoomedWithScale:(CGFloat)scale;
@end

@implementation UIFont (MultiplyLayout)

- (instancetype)zoomedWithScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:self.fontName size:self.pointSize * scale];
}

@end

@implementation UILabel (MultiplyLayout)
- (void)zoomCustomAttributesWithScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    self.font = [self.font zoomedWithScale:scale];
}
@end

@implementation UITextField (MultiplyLayout)
- (void)zoomCustomAttributesWithScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    self.font = [self.font zoomedWithScale:scale];
}
@end

@implementation UITextView (MultiplyLayout)
- (void)zoomCustomAttributesWithScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    self.font = [self.font zoomedWithScale:scale];
}
@end

@implementation UIButton (MultiplyLayout)
- (void)zoomCustomAttributesWithScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    self.titleLabel.font = [self.titleLabel.font zoomedWithScale:scale];
}
@end
```